# Duplicated value in UITableView when filter it from searchbar in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use this code please check

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *text,*text1;  if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
{

if ([tableView isEqual:ResultsTableView])
{

    text = self.results[indexPath.row];

} else
{
keydata  = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    arrayKey = [[dict objectForKey:keydata] allKeys];


    NSString *yourString = [arrayKey objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    text=yourString;
      }


cell.textLabel.text = text; else
{

    if ([tableView isEqual:ResultsTableView])
    {

        text1 = self.results[indexPath.row];

    } else
    {



        keydata1  = [sortedKeys1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        arrayKey1 = [[dict1 objectForKey:keydata1] allKeys];


        NSString *yourString = [arrayKey1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        text1=yourString;



    }

    cell.textLabel.text = text1;
return cell;

}
```

[image]

Comment: This code is completely unreadable...Please fix the formatting.

Comment: can you read now @Groot

Comment: No, the formatting makes it impossible. I tried to fix it myself but you seem to be missing a couple of braces ("{", "}") in your code. Especially right here "cell.textLabel.text = text; else"

Comment: yes their is another else part of seconde segment index @Groot

Comment: give the some time sister, I have suffered severe fever,